# Format Phone number in SQL using SUBSTR command but keep getting error

Tags: sql, oracle

Trying to list all instructors. Show salutation in all lower cases, last name in all upper cases and phone number in the format of '(xxx) xxx-xxxx'

I need to use the `SUBSTR` command but I keep getting an error.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT LOWER(salutation)
, UPPER(last_name)
,'(' + SUBSTRING(PhoneNumber, 1, 3) + ')' ,SUBSTRING(PhoneNumber, 4, 3) + '-' +SUBSTRING(PhoneNumber, 7, 4)
FROM instructor;
```

Error message:

> ORA-00904: "SUBSTRING": invalid identifier
> 00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
> *Cause:    
> *Action:
>  Error at Line: 6 Column: 122

EDIT #1 -

```
SELECT LOWER(salutation)
,  UPPER(last_name)
,  '(' + SUBSTRING||PhoneNumber, 1, 3|| + ')'
,  SUBSTRING||PhoneNumber, 4, 3|| + '-' +SUBSTRING||PhoneNumber, 7, 4||
FROM instructor;
```

Error message:

> ORA-00936: missing expression
> 00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
> *Cause:
> *Action:
> Error at Line: 7 Column: 1

Am I not putting the || in the right places?

EDIT #2 -

```
SELECT LOWER(salutation)
,  UPPER(last_name)
,  '(' ||SUBSTR(phone'(XXX)XXX-XXXX', 1, 13) || AS Phone_Number
FROM instructor;
```

Error message:

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

I just need to get the phone number from the table and format it in (xxx)xxx-xxx. I can run the following query:

```
SELECT LOWER(salutation)
, UPPER(last_name)
, SUBSTR('(XXX)XXX-XXXX', 1, 13) AS Phone_Number
FROM instructor;
```

But, I get the following response: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aScqg.png).  It needs to show the actual phone number.

Thank you or your time and patience!

Comment: Coming from MS SQL Server? Oracle uses ANSI SQL `||` for concatenation.

Comment: Please see the edit, maybe I am just not putting the || in the right place?

Comment: No, you didn't. It should be something like `'(' || SUBSTRING(PhoneNumber, 1, 3) || ')' ,`.

Comment: Substitute || for each instance of + in your original query

SELECT LOWER(salutation), UPPER(last_name),'(' || SUBSTRING(PhoneNumber, 1, 3) || ')' ,SUBSTRING(PhoneNumber, 4, 3) || '-' ||SUBSTRING(PhoneNumber, 7, 4)
FROM instructor;

Comment: Okay please see edit #2, thank you to everyone who is helping!

Comment: SELECT LOWER(salutation), UPPER(last_name),'(' || SUBSTRING(PhoneNumber, 1, 3) || ')'||SUBSTRING(PhoneNumber, 4, 3) || '-' ||SUBSTRING(PhoneNumber, 7, 4) FROM instructor

Comment: mtwadell it says that "SUBSTRING" is an invalid identifier

Comment: Forgot that one, Oracle has `SUBSTR()` instead.